# How to merge categorical values that are actually same in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have class-category column. It's named badly slightly but categorical values are actually same. They are all in same column. I need to replace all repeating values with 'class1'. there should be only 3 values in the column: class1, class2, standard.

- class_1
- class1
- Class_1
- Class1
- Standard
- class2

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is change `class_1` to `class1` then it's simple:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('class_1', 'class1', case=False)
```

Edit: Set case to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
g=df['column'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("\D", "", x))
df['column']=np.where(df['column'].str.contains('\d'),'Class'+g ,df['column'])
```

**Output**

```
    column
0   Class1
1   Class1
2   Class1
3   Class1
4   Standard
5   Class2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.lower().str.replace('_','')
print (df)
        col
0    class1
1    class1
2    class1
3    class1
4  standard
5    class2
```

Another idea is extract numeric from values by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), add `Class` string and last replace non numeric values by original by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['col'] = ('Class' + df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)).fillna(df['col'])
print (df)
        col
0    Class1
1    Class1
2    Class1
3    Class1
4  Standard
5    Class2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False))
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4    NaN
5      2
Name: col, dtype: objec

print (('Class' + df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)))
0    Class1
1    Class1
2    Class1
3    Class1
4       NaN
5    Class2
Name: col, dtype: object
```